# How do I set the new BM25Similarity algorithm on indexes created via the C# Azure search API?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

As per the new documenation, Azure are recommending you use the new BM25 similarity algorithm on newly created indexes in Azure search. See link here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/index-ranking-similarity

This is all very well for those who create the index manually via the Azure portal. But how do we add this via the C# azure search API? In the docs it shows a Json example

```
{
    "name": "indexName",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "id",
            "type": "Edm.String",
            "key": true
        },
        {
            "name": "name",
            "type": "Edm.String",
            "searchable": true,
            "analyzer": "en.lucene"
        },
        ...
    ],
    "similarity": {
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.BM25Similarity"
    }
}
```

However, in the API there is no similarity object on the Index object? Any pointers of adding this would be appreciated. Especially as we can't update existing Indexes!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [BM25Similarity](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.search.documents.indexes.models.bm25similarity?view=azure-dotnet) class is now available in the new [Azure.Search.Documents](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Search.Documents/) package. You can use it to create an index like so:

```cs
SearchIndex index = new SearchIndex("hotels")
{
    Fields =
    {
        new SimpleField("hotelId", SearchFieldDataType.String) { IsKey = true, IsFilterable = true, IsSortable = true },
        new SearchableField("hotelName") { IsFilterable = true, IsSortable = true },
        new SearchableField("description") { AnalyzerName = LexicalAnalyzerName.EnLucene },
        new SearchableField("tags", collection: true) { IsFilterable = true, IsFacetable = true },
        new ComplexField("address")
        {
            Fields =
            {
                new SearchableField("streetAddress"),
                new SearchableField("city") { IsFilterable = true, IsSortable = true, IsFacetable = true },
                new SearchableField("stateProvince") { IsFilterable = true, IsSortable = true, IsFacetable = true },
                new SearchableField("country") { IsFilterable = true, IsSortable = true, IsFacetable = true },
                new SearchableField("postalCode") { IsFilterable = true, IsSortable = true, IsFacetable = true }
            }
        }
    },
    Similarity = new BM25Similarity(),
    Suggesters =
    {
        // Suggest query terms from the hotelName field.
        new SearchSuggester("sg", "hotelName")
    }
};
```

See our [README](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/Azure.Search.Documents_11.1.0/sdk/search/Azure.Search.Documents/README.md) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

The similarity property is not yet available in the SDK. We are working on bringing it into the SDK asap. As of now, as you mentioned, the way you can test it out is through the REST API in the preview API. FYI, and you might already know it, but you can create an index using the REST API, but then continue using the SDK for any other operations (querying, indexing, etc.)

Comment: Thanks. But can you not put the similarity property in a preview SDK nuget package? Surely if it's already in REST API it's just a matter of you wrapping it for the SDK?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in my reply, we are working on it. We still have to go through the regular review/shipping process for any SDK changes. We are hoping for the similarity property to be in the next preview SDK release, but as of today, using the REST API is the only option.

Comment: @ramero-MSFT hi, I've tried using the REST Api to set similarity, but when I check the index definition, it does not appear (no affect on search query results as well from what I can see). I'm using api-version=2020-06-30. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share what your index creation request look like?

Comment: Sure, something like this:

`
{ 'name': 'search-index',
'fields': [],
'similarity': {
'@odata.type': 'Microsoft.Azure.Search.BM25Similarity',
'k1': 1.5,
'b': 0.7,
}`

just a note - fields is populated correctly. When I send this request, and check the index schema in the Azure portal, the similarity field is missing, but the others are updated. thanks

Comment: Can you try retrieving the index definition using the REST API (using version 2020-06-30)? The Similarity property only exist in 2019-05-06-preview, 2020-06-30-preview and 2020-06-30).
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/get-index

I'm not sure which version the portal is currently using, but if it's using 2019-05-06, that would explain why its not being returned.